# I am making e-commerce site using opencart when i go to index.php i am getting maintenance mode

Tags: opencart

I am making e-commerce site using opencart. i have configured it...but when i open now it is showing "We are maintaining the site so please come after sometime". I don't know how to get rid of this.
I tried deleting browsing history, open the site from a different location etc. but everywhere i am getting the same error(maintenance mode)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:
to enable the site you have to logon to admin and go to modification and press refresh button. as a best practice Whenever you enable / disable or delete a modification you need to click the refresh button to rebuild your modification cache!